# Judge countable and uncountable set

Tags: real-analysis

Is $(1,2]$ uncountable? And is $\mathbb{Q} \cap [0,1]$ countable?
I'm confused about how to judge if it is countable, and I think the $(1,2]$ and $[0,1]$ are from $\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: Opps, I mean is (1,2] uncountable

Comment: $(1,2]$ can be put in correspondence with $\Bbb R$, so it's uncountable; subsets of $\Bbb Q$ are countable

Answer (score 0):

First of all, $(a,b) , [a,b] , [a,b) , [a,b)$ have the same cardinality. And as any interval with $a\neq b$, $(1,2]$ is uncountable. The other set is a subtset of  $\mathbb{Q}$, so it can't be uncountable